# How to take photo automatically by handling the shutter button

Tags: swift3

understand iphone has the auto taking photo feature by setting the timer. after this press the shutter button to start.

I want to do something similar. So How to handle the Shutter Button programmatically after the camera has launched.

```
- implement: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate 

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {

var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!


}

//-- launch the camera

  @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

        imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

So, after the camera launch, how to programmatically handle the Shutter button like clicking it to take photo?

Answer (score 1):

> So, after the camera launch, how to programmatically handle the Shutter button like clicking it to take photo?

Tell the UIImagePickerController to `takePicture`.

Comment: Where to implement this? inside the Button function?  please show me how this is done? Thanks